# ipywidgets: looking for a solution to recursively close all child widgets when parent is closed

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

Suppose, I create a few nested widgets using ipywidgets, when I close the parent, an instance of `ipywidgets.Box` (using `parent.close()` call, I see that the child widgets are not automatically closed. Is it there any option to recursively close all children of a parent?